# HSlider event listener not triggered when value is updated Flex 3.5

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

I am writing a web application that will serve as a configuration for a random data generator that I have written in Java.  The values that I set in this application will write to xml.  The xml data is updated by a file called simulationParams.as and that file is added to each child in the "viewStack" so that when I change any of those values the simulationConfig file will be automatically updated.  The problem is that when I press the randomizeBtn the proper events are fired and the listeners grab those events.  My problem exists when I uncheck the randomize button.  For some reason an event is triggered or the listener isnt listening so that when I uncheck randomizeBtn the values go back to their last position or value on the slider. Ex. if my initial value is 0 then press randomize the slider will go to 100. The config file updates and all is well.  When I uncheck the randomizeBtn, the sliders value goes back 0 but the config file isnt update.  The same thing happens when I press the useDefaultBtn for both selected/unselected, nothing gets updated.

[Edited]

I have included a test application to help show my problem:
[snipplr.com/view/39260/testmxml](http://snipplr.com/view/39260/testmxml) (run this) 
[snipplr.com/view/39259/simulationconfigparamsas](http://snipplr.com/view/39259/simulationconfigparamsas) 
[snipplr.com/view/39257/organizationpanelmxml](http://snipplr.com/view/39257/organizationpanelmxml) 
[snipplr.com/view/39258/organizationtypesetting](http://snipplr.com/view/39258/organizationtypesetting)

The functions in question are:

```
randomizeBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
useDefaultBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
updateLastSliderPosition(currentChild:OrganizatyionTypeSettings):void
useSliderPosition(currentChild:OrganizatyionTypeSettings):void
creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
initSetting(setting:OrganizatyionTypeSettings):void
setMinuteCreationDelay(event:SliderEvent):void
setDelayVariance(event:SliderEvent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.  The problem is that the event listener I had `SliderEvent` didn't listen for the other type of event that was dispatched when I pressed the randomize or default button which is a `FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMMIT`; The fix for this add a second listener to my HSlider's then change the setSliderValue methods from `protected function mockSetFn(event:SliderEvent)` to `protected function mockSetFn(event:Event)` to handle all events.  The easy things awlays trip me up.

Comment: I quite confuse on this comment. Would you mind showing the code rather than a hint?